# Get field types of a content type

Tags: 8, nodes, entities

I am using Drupal 8.4. 
I am trying to dynamically create/update field data for a content type.

Is there a way to get the type of a field (e.g. text, image, file upload) for a content type?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the field type using Entity field manager.

```
$definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')
  ->getFieldStorageDefinitions('node');

$field_type = $definitions['field_image']->getType();
```

Comment: That works, but depending on what you are working with, there are easier ways, e.g. when you already have an entity object, you can just do $entity->getFieldDefinition('field_image')->getType()

Comment: Its not working. It gave an Unexpected error `"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException</em>: The &quot;article_text&quot; entity type does not exist. in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager-&gt;getDefinition()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">133</em> of <em class="placeholder">core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager.php</em>)."`

Comment: Here the solution is provided for generic node; instead I want to make it work for a content type.

Comment: @Kiran a content type is a variant of a node. field storages are the same for all nodes, they just might or might not exist on a certain content type/bundle. That means for the type, you don't need article_text, you just need node. Only if you need something like the lable then you need to call getFieldDefinitions() which has two arguments, entity type and bundle